# HTML Form: Insert id into related table

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm relatively new to both PHP and MySQL and here's my first question:

I have 3 tables. One as the "main table" and two as basically lists/categories of which I can choose and relate them to my main table.

Table 1

```
id    name    hobby    color
1     Peter   1        2
2     Simon   3        2
3     Lisa    2        3
```

Table 2 would then be hobbies

```
id    name
1     Swimming
2     Football
3     Piano
```

Same with table 3 and colors.

```
id    name
1     red
2     blue
3     green
```

Now, I have managed to "relate" the tables with *PHPMyAdmin*, but how can I do the following:

I want to insert data into the first table. The problem is, I want to insert a simple number in hobbies or colors, but within the HTML form there should be the text related to the is.

So if I choose 'green'(as a string), it should insert 3 into Table 1.

I hope it's clear what I am looking to do. 
Thanks for every help in advance.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

`INSERT INTO table1 (name, hobby, color)
VALUES
('Tom', 
(SELECT id from Table2 WHERE name = 'Swimming'),
(SELECT id from Table3 WHERE name = 'green')
);`

Note, if order for this to work correctly the name column must be unique, otherwise you could get 'query returns more than one row' error.

Also, I would write this statement as a stored procedure for security and additional error checking.

Comment: @Gervs's suggestion below also works but it reveals ID values which can be a security concern (sorry I don't have enough rep to comment ;P)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in HTML

```
<select name="hobbies">
    <option value="1">Swimming</option>
    <option value="2">Football</option>
    <option value="3">Piano</option>
</select>
```